# Variable value not passing for a pipe grep to remote ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I would like to run a command like ps -ef | grep xyz using ssh into a remote machine.

I can run manually the command like the below and it works.

`ssh -n $server 'ps -ef | grep xyz'`

I try to do the same in a script like the below:

```
server=abc
listener=xyz
echo server is $server
echo listener is $listener
ssh -n $server 'ps -ef | grep $listener' > s.out
```

When I try to run this, the value of the listener is not passed.

I tried adding `export listener=xyz` part of the ssh command but it still didn't work.

Can you please hint me on what I should change to have the local environment value passed to remote ssh.

Comment: _In some cases_ including this one but not all, you don't need to do the `grep` remotely, so `{ ssh -n $server ps -ef } | grep $listener` (unnecessary { grouping } added for clarity) is an alternative.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, when I added the `{ }` for clarity I forgot to add `;` as required by shell syntax. To be exact either `{ ssh -n $server ps -ef; } | grep $listener` or simpler but not quite as obvious `ssh -n $server ps -ef | grep $listener`